# BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR build setting not set

Tags: ios, xcode

A library I'm using for an iOS app requires that during the build process, the build setting `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` be set. How can I set it? I tried setting the value of `Header Search Paths` to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`, as the book `iOS 5 Pro Tools` [mentions](http://books.google.com/books?id=ydVnKoplt1cC&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR%20xcode&source=bl&ots=pyttxlOoiG&sig=RTyiRbDSI2x4JRJ6nOFbw68e8ag&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_2rtUZm1J6fuyQGei4D4Cg&ved=0CGMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR%20xcode&f=false):

[image]

Comment: You probably already solved this or moved on, but I happened to see the variable being set by a command line script. See http://gabrielrinaldi.me/ios-app-versioning-with-git-tag/